# How do I align text/class with the button in the <style> tag when it won't center in css or style tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I put `margin-auto` in the `toggle` class [on my site](http://mynameisjavascript.x10host.com/JSBASICS.html). It sort of went it the middle but it didn't align with the button. Do I need to do something in CSS or JavaScript and what should I place there?

```html
  <style>
  .toggler { width: 500px; height: 200px; position: relative; margin-top:0; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom:0;
   }
      #button { padding: .5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
      #effect { width: 240px; height: 170px; padding: 0.4em; position: relative; }
      #effect h3 { margin: 0; padding: 0.4em; text-align: center; }
      .ui-effects-transfer { border: 2px dotted gray; }
      .kiri{text-align:center;}
</style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    // run the currently selected effect
    function runEffect() {
      // get effect type from
      var selectedEffect = $( "#effectTypes" ).val();
 
      // Most effect types need no options passed by default
      var options = {};
      // some effects have required parameters
      if ( selectedEffect === "scale" ) {
        options = { percent: 50 };
      } else if ( selectedEffect === "transfer" ) {
        options = { to: "#button", className: "ui-effects-transfer" };
      } else if ( selectedEffect === "size" ) {
        options = { to: { width: 200, height: 60 } };
      }
 
      // Run the effect
      $( "#effect" ).effect( selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
    };
 
    // Callback function to bring a hidden box back
    function callback() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $( "#effect" ).removeAttr( "style" ).hide().fadeIn();
      }, 1000 );
    };
 
    // Set effect from select menu value
    $( "#button" ).on( "click", function() {
      runEffect();
      return false;
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>

<body>
   <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="CONTACT.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="JSBASICS.html">JQUERY TIPS</a></li>
      <li><a href="JQUERYBASICS.html">JS TIPS</a></li>
      <li><a href="INFO.html">Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="ABOUT.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


  <h2>Jquery Tips</h2>
  <p id="js">JavaScript/jQuery is a programming language that you can use to add interactivity to your web page.</p>
  <p id="poo"> if you put your mouse over the sentence above there will be a light blue highlight the lightgray background that was made using the <a href="https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/onmouseover-html-element/"><span class="pink">onmouse event.</span></a>
  
 <div class="footer">
 <span class="flatorange">@2016-20XX  &#8226 Nia Daniels  &#8226 FINAL EXAM &#8226 CIST1520 </span><br>
 <span class="flatblue">Scripting Technologies</span><br>
 <span class="flatgreen">Mr.Cash</span><br>
 </div>

 <div class="toggler">
 <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">2 Jquery Effects</h3>
   <p id="hmm">eres una mujer o hombre? soy una mujer.  quiero una pizza. queires una pizza o no?</p>
 </div>
 </div>

  <div class="kiri">
<select name="effects" id="effectTypes">
  <option value="bounce">Bounce</option>
  <option value="clip">Clip</option>
</select></div>
 <div class="kiri">
<button id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Run Le Effect</button></div>
<script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin: 0 auto;` to both `.toggler` and `#effect` and it should do the trick. Since you set a width on `#effect` you'll need the auto margin to handle the centering for you.